# Using Java-classes with C#

Tags: c#, java

I have a project written in Java (>1.5).

Is it possible to write parts of the project with C#?
For instance the GUI and calling the methods and instantiate the classes written in java?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something called [Java Language Conversion Assistant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/vjsharp/aa718346.aspx) for .NET. You can convert your Java classes to c# and start coding.

There is also something called [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/) (not free).

Comment: Or if you don't mind the heavy class library, use IKVM.NET. https://github.com/jessielesbian/ikvm/

Answer (score 19):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source intraprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 8):

Not without something like [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/) - or using web services etc to communicate between the two sides. Basically it's likely to be much more work than either rewriting your existing project code in C# or writing the GUI in Java.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not possible with dll approach ? Rewriting is an option for small project rewriting 100.000 line for example might be costly ...

Comment: You'd need to be running both the CLR and the JVM - and the two VMs don't know about each other's objects.

Comment: You mean, Ilya's answer is not working?

Comment: Ilya's answer only applies if you're using the Excelsior JET JRE, and only up to v3.7.

Comment: I edited my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

**It seems like my solution is very limited. and apply only to specific version of java.**

I probably will stay with old good C :) Can't imagine how to work without shared libraries :)

This [document](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/kb/000001.html) explain how to create a dll from java and use it in C code. I'm not C# or java expert but i'm sure that you can load external dll's in C# as well. So not a complete solution but good starting point, IMHO. 
Generally dll it's a perfect way to mixing languages.

Comment: Note that that document only applies to a particular JRE, and only up to a particular (fairly old - 2005) version.

Comment: Like i mention i'm not a java expert. Does it mean that that creating dll in java is not trivial ? How one share libraries in java ?

Comment: Ilya: Java libraries are shared in JAR-files. They are essentially compressed archives (zip I believe) that contain the Java bytecode compiled files and other resources.

Answer (score 2):

In simple way you can pack your java classes to jar file then 
In C# use *Process* class for execute and map IO stream

Comment: any example, please

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this a few years ago (2005 I believe) and I liked JNBridgePro as the best third party product to do this. Check it out here http://www.jnbridge.com/

Good luck!