# Importing Java libraries into C#

Tags: c#, java, zip

So, I have written my code to .zip files in C#, but when I import the libraries I have the following:

```
Using java.util;
Using java.util.zip;
Using java.io;
```

But, these are underlined in red, with the error message, `The type or namespace "java" could not be found`

Is there some reference I need to add?

Comment: Have you looked at the answer to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c

Answer (score 11):

You can't import Java libraries directly to .NET.

You should use [`IKVM`](http://www.ikvm.net/) if you want to use Java in .NET, though there are zip libraries for .NET - here is one, [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

Additionally, the syntax is `using`, not `Using` - it is all lower case.

Answer (score 6):

Well unless you're using J# (which became obsolete quite a while ago) you shouldn't be *trying* to use Java libraries in .NET. You should use the .NET framework libraries instead.

If you want a port of the Java zip libraries to .NET, there's one available at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/). That should make it reasonably easy to port your C# code to use the right libraries - but for almost all tasks, you shouldn't be trying to use anything from Java; you should use the idiomatic .NET-based tool which solves the same problem. Sometimes there's a project which shares the same philosophies and possibly original implementation roots (e.g. NHibernate for Hibernate) but sometimes there are completely different options available.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to import an actual Java library into c#. You may want to consider looking at [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) - "*bridge between Java and .NET*".

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. One word - [JavApi](https://javapi.codeplex.com/).