# Playing the guitar in C#

Tags: c#, java, audio, guitar

I came across a programming assignment from Princeton University that deals with simulating guitar string plucks (see [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall10/cos126/assignments/guitar.html)).

I tried solving it to C# but I am currently stuck with actually playing the sound. In the example they do it by calling StdAudio.play() with a double value in the range [-1;1]. StdAudio is a class provided by Princeton (and can be found [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/StdAudio.java.html)).

So basically my question boils down to: How would I go about porting the StdAudio class to C#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the second answer here may help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051989/importing-java-libraries-into-c-sharp - **edit** if thats not the question, it looks like taking time to figure out how to convert the code yourself

Answer (score 0):

Instead of porting StdAudio to C#, have a look at this

http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/generating-various-audio-waveforms-in-c-sharp/

It shows a way to create audio from arbitrary values.

Comment: Generating audio waveforms is not the problem, playing on the other hand is.