# How to create and use class instances in C# from JAR files?

Tags: java, c#

I'm aware of all the other questions about this topic, but I haven't found a good solution for my problem. Currently I am trying to use Java code in my C# project. I've already tried to convert the `JAR` files into `.DLL` files with IKVM, but this didn't work for me because the `JAR` files are to complicated to translate into C# because not every component, which were used in Java, can be found in C#. The normal call of the `JAR` file doesn't work for me either because I need to work with the class instances of the declared classes in the Java code.

Back to my question: Does anybody know how I could use Java code in my project? I've heard that it may be possible to implement Java code like it would be native, is that true? Note that I've to work with the class instances of the classes declared in the Java code.

I highly appreciate any kind of help, sheers!

---

**Edit:**
My work around would be that I include batch files, which are calling the JAR files. I will include these batch files into my C# Project and work with the batch files. This may be a even better approach for me because every input and output of the JAR files are done via XML files.

Comment: If the usual interop approaches aren't working for you, is it not possible to rewrite the Java library in C#?

Comment: @Llama I also thought about that, but that would be too much work, since they get updated twice a year and are very big. It would take to long to translate

Answer (score 1):

This kind of mixup are not generally a good approach. I think the `.Net Framework` is very mature and you can find everything you want to do your work.

I would suggest you the following approach :

1. You can wrap your `Java` library in a `REST API` and call it in your `C#` code. Your `REST API` can be hosted on an external server or use an [embedded server](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or even a `spring boot` project.
2. You can read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051989/importing-java-libraries-into-c-sharp) for more details.

Comment: Haven't thought about a REST API. Actually a very good idea, thanks!

Comment: You can approach this like the implementation of a `facade` or `adapter` pattern.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern