# Integrating java class to be used in vb.net application

Tags: java, vb.net

I have been asked to create a project in vb.net which needs to integrate a java class created by Apple (Autoingestion.class) to pull sales records and so on.

I found out a couple of questions here on stackoverflow but none of the answers given worked for me when trying to integrate this java class in my .net application.

For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c) seemed to be what I really needed but when trying to compile this java class (I decompiled it first using Java Decompiler), it generally throws some errors.

All I need is to use this class in my application to invoke a method.
Does anyone know how to pull this out without much ninja-ing?

EDIT: Here is the [decompiled code from Autoingestion.class](http://shrib.com/Ob65MAKa)

Comment: Did you use ikvm as described in the accepted _answer_? It does not mention decompiling at all.

Comment: Oded, the file I received is a compiled java class, so the file extention is .class. In order to create a .jar out of it, I needed to decompile the code so I could create a new java project with it and eventually create the .jar to pass to the ikvm.
So, as I mentioned, the code decompiled doesn't even run. I can post the code here to exemplify.
Also, I tried to create a .jar out of the compiled Autoingestion.class file and when integrating the .dll created by ikvm, my .net app couldn't access any members of this dll.

Comment: [the jar command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.htm) takes files and/or directories as input and does not compile java source (that is javac).  You do not need to decompile/recompile your classes to add them to a jar file.  In the end a jar file is just a zip file with some extra meta-data content.

Comment: @krock, I tried to compile a .jar with the compiled java class and passed it through ikvm as suggested but the generated dll didn't expose any methods to my .net application.

Comment: Looking at the decompiled source all it seems to do is make a post over https, with some params that are given on the command line and then reads back the response and saves it to a file.  IMO you may as well just rewrite that in .Net by hand.

Comment: That's what I'd rather do but I was asked not to and to maintain the code as it is right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution here (other than rewriting the java code in .Net -see above comments) is to simply execute the existing java code from .Net since the class concerned contains a `main method`.  i.e. something like this assuming the java class is in the working dir of your .Net app (and java is on your path):

```
Shell("java Autoingestion <options>")
```

this keeps original functionality and is uses similar commands you currently do.

Comment: Krock, thanks for your solution, I will mark it as the answer. I already managed to use the dll in .net. Apparently, what I was doing wrong was that I had to rename the main method to something else and then use ikvm again. This time I was able to get it working. Kudos to the developer of ikvm, it's an amazing app.

Comment: In the end I preferred your solution to save myself the hassle of having to generate a dll everytime Apple updates that file. Thanks again.