# Google Speech Recognition API for Windows Phone (Not Bing Recognizer)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Are there any Google Speech Recognition API document filed for Window Phone ? I am currently doing my Final Year Project as a student and need implement Google Speech Recognition .

I saw app's like **VoiceTranslator** For Windows Phone which is powered by Google's Engines.
Hence , is there any document that I could refer to to implement Google Speech Recognition API in my window phone Application ?

Or Are there any other Speech Recognizer Service I can benefits from?

Comment: Windows phones exist? Never seen one :)

Comment: Haha... Exist , Its my Final Year Project. So I have no choice . Using Window Phone 8 ( Nokia Lumia )...

Comment: Quite a nice phone comparing to android .. Lag free, Nice Battery Life, Clean UI, Easy to use, nice camera ... But I still prefer iDevices :)

Answer (score 0):

J.A.R.V.I.S. Java Speech API uses Google services for the synthesizer and recognizer. Internet connection is required for the service to function.

What you can do is to take the precompiled JAR ([here](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api/releases)) and include it in your C# application. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/512247/2777098) SO post -- *Use a .jar java library API in C#?* for information on how to include the JAR in .NET program. One thing to note though, I believe this is not an official solution provided by Google.

Comment: Hi Isabel , form my researches. I find out that Winodw Phone does not have enough library to support ikvmc .

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Google Speech Engine with http connection. It's a kind of hook.

More info here: http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

I made it work for Android, but for Wp it is also feasible.