# Use a jar java API in c# program

Tags: java, c#, api, jar, visual-studio-2019

I want to import the APIs and use them to build my c# program. This Java API also comes with a .java file which shows how to use the library but I cannot see the code inside the .jar. I searched and found some tools about this purpose but i would like to know the best way to do it.  Thank you!

Comment: Is it the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512124/use-a-jar-java-library-api-in-c?

Comment: @Konras Neitzel yes exactly the same problem! So I can find the answer there! Thanks a lot!