# Running Java code in C#

Tags: c#, java, silverlight

I am writing a `silverlight application` using c#. For the project I need to be able to compile and download a program to an external drive. I have the code to do this however it is written in Java.

The code is extensive and would take an excessive amount of time to translate all of it into c#. Is there an alternate way to translate the code into c# or is there a way to run java code within a c# project?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Comment: Is your java code just code? or is it an executable jar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129989/how-to-call-java-code-from-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always compile it as an executable and run it with `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IKVM.net](http://www.ikvm.net/) to convert the jar to a dll

Comment: There's no need to convert the jar file to a dll since C# can simply execute it by calling `java -jar yourJarFile`.

Comment: @HovercraftFUllOfEels um, unless of course the developer of the C# application wants to embed java code without having to rely on the user having java or forcing the user to install it, or the C# developer wants to be able access java types in code, or the Java developer C# types, so on and so forth. Should actually look at the project......

Answer (score 0):

In google you can find a online service for it or change same code witch doesn't work