# Can a java "unmanaged" code be imported to C# through [DllImport] attribute?

Tags: java, c#, dll, dllimport, unmanaged

While I am studying about the Attribute classes in c#(System.Attribute), I just came across with [DllImport] attribute. According to the web and as I understood, it is to import unmanaged implementation from a DLL to a managed C# coding. If I am right, can this attribute be used to import java implementations too?

Comment: Short answer: NO. For a solution see [this better focused question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/129989/60761)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DllImport` wraps up the `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` functions of Win32. These functions are used to import from unmanaged modules. Java code is not unmanaged, and so you cannot use `DllImport` to call Java code.

Comment: Can you please be kind enough to explain me the exact meaning of "unmanaged"? I thought it was for all the non C# language. I am quiet new to C# that's why. @David Heffernan

Comment: Java is managed just as .net is. In place of the .net runtime there is the JVM. By unmanaged here we mean a classic Win32 PE file such as you might make from C++ source code. Another term used is native code. It's all a bit woolly but the bottom line is that Java does not quality. You readily cannot make a DLL from Java that can be loaded using `LoadLibrary`. What you could do is make a DLL that exported functions that would then create an instance of the JVM, load up some compiled Java code, and call into it using the Java runtime API. But that's a serious undertaking.

Comment: But that would not be the way to go. Follow the link that Henk gave you.