# Connect to IBM Emulator 5250 iseries Communication

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect to IBM emulator 5250 iseries communication through C# code. The emulator extension is .HOD and is installed in c:\Users\Public\IBM\Emuator folder. How can I connect to this emulator?

[image]

Comment: This is not really on-topic for SO. So if it is that urgent you should research your problem in a more appropriate place.

Comment: As far as I know, ACS is a Java program. Not really sure what `.HOD` is. Maybe something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129989/2296441) will help you.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [EHLLAPI With the Access Client Solutions Emulator](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1010639), ACS supports applications built to use the Emulator High Level Language API (EHLLAPI) and Personal Communications Session API (PCSAPI).

The older Windows based IBM i Access production supported

- Emulator High Level Language API (EHLLAPI)
- Personal Communications Session API (PCSAPI)
- Host Access Class Library (HACL)
- Dynamic Data Exchange (DDE)

The emulator old i Access product (aka Client Access) was a subset of the functionality in the emulator used by the separate Personal Communications product.

The best place for documentation about the emulator APIs is probably with the Personal Communications product.  Start here [Introduction to Emulator APIs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_13.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/emulator_programming06.htm)

However, I can't imagine using any of these for a new project.  Ask your RPG developers if they can provide a web service you can call.