# How can I used Oracle cloud infrastructure JAVA SDK in .Net application with C# to access storage

Tags: c#, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

As per my knowledge oracle oracle cloud infrastructure API can be used in .Net application to access database.But I don't know if it is possible with JAVA SDK

Comment: We are trying to understand your scenario to assess the improvements we could make in the OCI developer experience going ahead. If you would be interested in contributing by sharing your use-case in some more detail, please shoot an email to Sumit Dey at sumit.kumar.dey at oracle.com. Disclosure: Sumit and I work for the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Developer Experience team

Comment: Oracle Cloud .NET SDK is now available and perhaps would be the best way to use Oracle Cloud Infrastructure APIs for your .NET application. Refer this blog to get kick-started on it : https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/oci-sdk-for-net-is-now-available-for-your-net-projects

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to more generally be 'can I call Java functionality from C#?' I suspect the answer is yes, but I don't have the details on that. Please take a look at these posts related to that:

- [How to call Java code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129989/how-to-call-java-code-from-c)
- https://github.com/jni4net/jni4net/wiki/Calling-Java-in-C%23
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajyadav123/invoking-java-code-in-C-Sharp-net/

However, I wanted to make sure you know about the [C# signing sample](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm?tocpath=Developer%20Tools%20%7CREST%20APIs%20%7C_____4#CSharp) that we have available in the OCI documentation, which calls out how to make HTTP requests to OCI services using C# code. This would allow you to not have to use the Java SDK at all from your C# application, and instead use only C# code to talk to OCI.

Comment: you can easily make in-process calls between C# code and Java packages through our product www.javonet.com. This could be a great approach to isolate from the PaaS technology of preferred Cloud service. It works also to call .NET DLLs from Java.