# how to compile and execute java code file in c# dynamically by passing params

Tags: java, c#, dynamic

I have a requirement to compile and run java programs from C# dynamically by passing parameters.
Ex: below is java code i have to execute this code from c# by passing parameters num1, num2. How to do in c#?

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
 public class AddTwoNumbers2 {

public int CalAdd(int num1, int num2) {   
  return num1 + num2;
    
  }
 }
```

I am looking for calling Java code file in c# like below, python code called in c# example code

```
       var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        //try
        //{

        var compilerOptions = (PythonCompilerOptions)engine.GetCompilerOptions();
     ErrorSinkProxyListener(errorSink);
        var scriptSource = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\download_nrlist.py", Encoding.UTF8, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.File);
        var compiledCode = scriptSource.Compile();
        compiledCode.Execute(scope);
        engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Nidec\PythonScript\download_nrlist.py", scope);

        //get function and dynamically invoke
        var calcAdd = scope.GetVariable("CalcAdd");           
        result = calcAdd(34, 8); // returns 42 (Int32)
```

Comment: You run the same commands you would normally do, i.e. `javac` to compile the code, then `java` to run it, you just run the commands from C#. If you don't know how to run `javac` or `java`, how are you running the Java code to test it? If you don't know how to run commands from C#, do some **research**, i.e. a *web search*. Since all of that is very easy, why did you need to ask? Or more specifically, what is stopping you from doing any of those things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call Java code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129989/how-to-call-java-code-from-c)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `java` run commands inside a `.sh` or `.bat` file and then use `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` in your C# method to execute that shell script/batch file.

Code snippet:

```
class MyProcess {
        // Opens urls and .html documents using Internet Explorer.
        void OpenWithArguments()
        {
            // url's are not considered documents. They can only be opened
            // by passing them as arguments.
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "www.northwindtraders.com");

            // Start a Web page using a browser associated with .html and .asp files.
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.htm");
            Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "C:\\myPath\\myFile.asp");
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            MyProcess myProcess = new MyProcess();
            myProcess.OpenWithArguments();
        }
}
```

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-5.0)